# Where is rel="modal:close" documented?

Tags: html

I came across the code;

```
<p>Thanks for clicking.  That felt good.  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
```

Clicking is actually executing a modal:close command on a modal div. (See http://jquerymodal.com/).

Does anyone know where this is documented?

Comment: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal

Comment: Looks like the entire jQuery plugin is documented on its GitHub page: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#closing

Comment: Yes.  I'm just wondering what kind of HTML rel="modal:close" is. Normally rel specifies a relationship to a linked item.  This seems to actually be executing something.